# How to rearrange MySQL columns?

Tags: mysql

I need to move the position of existing columns (for better visibility).

How can this be done without affecting the data?

Comment: Not dupes: the first is about swapping data, the second is about "sqlyog".

Comment: A save way is to use PHPMyAdmin's "Move Columns" feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682789/1066234

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[Modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767467/819417) also works. Have a look:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name column_definition AFTER other_column;
```

The full definition of the column must be repeated exactly if you are just changing the order.

The best way to get the `column_definition` is to dump the table definition with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`.

Comment: Could anyone explain the difference between CHANGE COLUMN and MODIFY please?  Is MODIFY a lighter weight operation?  Does it not lock the table?  Thanks.  UPDATE: It looks a lot like CHANGE and MODIFY are synonyms, where MODIFY was added for Oracle users. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: This works but be aware that (on my setup at least) moving a column removes any auto_increment settings from that column.

Comment: You will also lose your default value if you don't specify it in the alter statement.

Comment: You must put the whole column definition including AUTOINCREMENT, NULL / NOT NULL,DEFAULT value, COMMENT...

Answer (score 57):

The only way I know is to change the column. You would first extract your column definition using [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) and issue an [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE foo
CHANGE COLUMN bar
bar COLUMN_DEFINITION_HERE
FIRST;
```

Or if you want it *after* a certain other column:

```
... AFTER OTHER_COLUMN;
```

Comment: I had problem with `BEFORE` instead I used `FIRST`

Comment: There is no BEFORE in MySQL syntax [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html), only AFTER and FIRST

Comment: If you only want to reorder columns `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY` is preferable as it doesn't ask you for column name again in the syntax format, which you can rename a column accidentally whereas `MODIFY` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

1. Alter Table table_name modify column_name column_datatype first;
2. Alter Table table_name modify column_name column_datatype After other_column_name;

Comment: This is not just `column_datatype` but the full column definition including collation, default value, comment...

Answer (score 3):

Based on @VKGS answer:

If your table called **language** is:

```
|      description    |         name     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      fbi agent      |         jane     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      mi6 agent      |         kurt     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And you want to make, the column `name` the first column instead of `description`, execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE language MODIFY description varchar(100) AFTER name;
```

Don't forget type of the column.

Comment: With modify you must put the whole column definition including `NULL / NOT NULL`,`DEFAULT value`, `COMMENT`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sql query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN misplaced_column Column-definition AFTER other_column;
```

Here in *Column-definition* is full column definition. To see the column definition if you are using phpMyAdmin click on structure tab. Then click on change link on desired column. Then without modifying any thing click save. It will show you the sql. Copy the sql and just add `AFTER other_column` at the end.

If you like to bring the *misplaced_column* to the first position then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN misplaced_column Column-definition FIRST;
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Structure` and click `Move Columns` and then just drag the columns to rearrange.

Comment: You are not metionning what tool you are using.

Comment: Sounds like probably phpMyAdmin.