# Rails 4 migration: how to reorder columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, ruby-on-rails-4

I learned that `add_column` has an `:after` option to set where the column gets inserted. Too bad I learned about it :after adding a bunch.

How can I write a migration to simply reorder columns?

Comment: You could dump you Database to save the Data ; re-order your Schema.rb to put the timestamps columns at the end of the create_table's block ; run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and then re-import your Data

Comment: Now, that's an undocumented feature : [You have to read core sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7860bf11d862a6eb1bd9ada85bcd97f17a2cb536/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L278) to find it. Just for reference, I've checked rename_column code : it does not offer this feature (sorry it doesn't help).

Comment: Use SQL in a migration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095481/easy-way-to-re-order-columns

Comment: @Zabba That's not a bad idea. Could you submit it as an answer, preferably with some code to show the syntax for executing raw MySQL in a migration.

Comment: I just pointed out another answer on SO, but Stefan shows a nice way to do it without SQL..

Comment: @MrYoshiji: This didn't work for me. The `rake` commands re-order the columns, that's correct. But when I re-import my legacy data using an SQL dump the column sort order gets messed up again.

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Good overall point except that you should not modify the `schema.rb` directly. Create a migration instead. I quote here the rails documentation on `schema.rb` [rails 5.1]: "*This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record*". So: 1/ erase the relevant migrations 2/ run `rake db:drop db:create` (this will empty the `schema.rb`), 3/ create a migration, 4/ edit it so as to add the columns in the right order, an then 5/ run it with `rake db:migrate`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When using MySQL, you can call `change_column`, but you have to repeat the column type (just copy and paste it from your other migration):

```
def up
  change_column :your_table, :some_column, :integer, after: :other_column
end
```

Or if you have to reorder multiple columns in one table:

```
def up
  change_table :your_table do |t|
    t.change :some_column, :integer, after: :other_column
    # ...
  end
end
```

`change_column` calls `ALTER TABLE` under the hood. From the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> You can also use `FIRST` and `AFTER` in `CHANGE` or `MODIFY` operations to
> reorder columns within a table.

Note that this approach doesn't work with PostgreSQL. (see [Alter column positions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position))

Comment: Good catch. I was not aware it was doable through ALTER TABLE.

Comment: @OlivierElMekki I've added a link to the MySQL documentation

Comment: @Stefan Can I get away with using `def change` instead of `up` and `down`?

Comment: @Emerson Rails currently can't reverse `change_column`. Do you really have to revert the column order?

Comment: @Stefan Nope. I don't need to revert it. I just wanted to make sure it wouldn't break anything. If that's the case, should I use `up` instead of `change`?

Comment: You can use `up` for a "one way" migration. Using `change` will raise an exception upon rollback if Rails can't reverse the migration definition unless you're [using `reversible`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-reversible).

Comment: None of this works with postgres- it's impossible to reorder columns http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683264/165673

Comment: @Yarin Thanks! That saved me some precious time