# How do I re-order table columns in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activeadmin, schema.rb

I created a model in my Rails app and realized after some time that I had forgotten to add some attributes, and later added them via a generated migration.

I now realize that the order of the attribute columns in `schema.rb` is the order that they will appear in a generated resource view in ActiveAdmin.

I want to reorder the columns when I view that model in ActiveAdmin, and the only way I have thought to do so is by changing the column order in the database.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899011/rails-4-migration-how-to-reorder-columns/18900396) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683147/is-it-safe-to-reorder-columns-in-schema-rb-for-rails-4-postgres/31683264#31683264), and attempted to run a database migration using `change_table` or `change_column`. This had no resulting change.

This is migration I ran, which had no result:

```
class Reordercolumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_table :student_details do |t|
      t.change :exact_length, :text, after: :length_of_stay
      t.change :returned_home, :boolean, after: :spouse_name
      t.change :has_spouse, :boolean, after: :expectation
    end
  end
end
```

Looking to view attribute columns in ActiveAdmin in a particular order,  I ran a database migration to change columns, but the migration is not reordering the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorder columns in ActiveAdmin? Let's do it in corresponding `admin/student_detail.rb` file

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :exact_length
  column :returned_home
  column :has_spouse
end

show do
  attributes_table do
    row :title
    row :returned_home
    row :has_spouse
  end
end
```

More info about customizing [index](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) and [show](https://activeadmin.info/6-show-pages.html) views you can find in the docs