# Change Position of Existing column in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have one Column in my Table, i want to change its position from last to second, can anyone please help me to do that. thanks in Advance.i have idea about `after: column_name`, but its apply while Adding new column. How to change position of Exciting column?

```
User
  first_name
  last_name
  middle_name
  mobile_NO
```

i want like this

```
User
  first_name
  mobile_no
  last_name
  middle_name
```

Comment: What rails version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call change_column migration, like shown below:

```
def up
  change_column :your_table, :some_column, :integer, after: :other_column
end
```

For more information have look into this: [Rails 4 migration: how to reorder columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899011/rails-4-migration-how-to-reorder-columns)

Comment: Thank you, i was doing same, just missing `DataType` `integer`, rest of all i completed, anyway, thanks again.