# Rearrange order of fields in a sql table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

My aim is to alter table course_info whose present schema is

course_info( course_no , course_name , course_prerequisite  , cost )

into

course_info( course_no , course_prerequisite , course_name , cost )

I tried the sql statement as per the link 
[How to move columns in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table)

Statement throwing error:

`alter table course_info modify course_prerequisite number(8) after course_name ;`

but it is giving me error

ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Comment: Please format the code

Comment: Why do you want to do that exactly?

Comment: @Mat my input data .sql file has different order in entries so when i run that file it throws me error , thats why i am trying to rearrange the fields of my table

Comment: Well you'll have to re-create your table or use `dbms_redefinition`, or modify your .sql file.

Comment: If the input sql file has a different order, why don't you change that?

Comment: @Mat thanks that post will work .

Comment: `create table course_info_dup as select course_no,course_prerequisite , course_name , cost from course_info;`

and then drop the course_info table then
rename course_info_dup to course_info