# How to move columns in java DB Apache Derby?

Tags: jdbc, derby, javadb

I need to change specific column's position
I tried Ted Hopp's solution in [Move Column in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table)

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES MODIFY COLUMN fname VARCHAR(25) AFTER password
```

and i got this error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "MODIFY" at line 1, column 22.
```

So any idea how to do it with Derby

Comment: Why do you need to move the column? You can always re-arrange the columns in the order you prefer in your SELECT statement, or in your program after you retrieve the data.

Comment: i have a db and i did some changes, so i wanted to sort columns because i knew it is possible in mysql. and i was wondering if derby have the same feature or not. :)

Comment: If it's really important to you, you could: (a) create a new table, with the columns in the order you want, (b) insert into newtable select column-list from oldtable (c) drop table oldtable, (d) rename table newtable to oldtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derby uses `ADD COLUMN` ([docs](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES ADD COLUMN fname VARCHAR(25)
```

There is no way to insert columns before or after a certain column; they are always appended.