# Can I move a column with a Laravel 5.7 migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.7

My migration looks like this, but it doesn't seem to do anything, or even throw any errors:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id')
            ->first()
            ->change();
    });
}
```

I know you can do it when *creating* a column, like this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('id')
    ->first();
```

It'd definitely be possible with a raw MySQL statement, but perhaps Laravel migrations simply doesn't support moving a column after it's been created?

FYI, using PHP 7.1, Laravel 5.7, and MariaDB/MySQL 5.5

Comment: If there is no data, drop column and create new. I presume there is still data you want to preserve, then you can use bit hacky way from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340778/laravel-migration-re-organising-column-order#answer-42194661) answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel migration re-organising column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340778/laravel-migration-re-organising-column-order)