# H2 Database - Reorder columns using SQL

Tags: sql, h2

I have a H2 database with 16 million entries and no primary key. I successfully added an auto-incrementing primary key using the following statements:

```
ALTER TABLE
    PUBLIC.ADDRESSES ADD ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE
    PUBLIC.ADDRESSES ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

Now the problem is, that the column order is `STREET, HOUSENUMBER, ..., ID`, but I would like `ID` to be the first column of the table. It looks like there is a corresponding `ALTER TABLE` statement MySQL ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table)), but I'm unable to adapt it to H2.

Long story short: How can I change the column order to `ID, STREET, HOUSENUMBER ...`? Is there a solution similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE "ADDRESSES" MODIFY COLUMN "ID" BEFORE "STREET";
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: There's no standard way to do it, and in some products your only choice is to create a new table and copy the data across. It's not in the standard because, as much as possible, you shouldn't rely on the columns having *any* particular order. Can't speak to whether h2 has any facilities that will help you here though.

Comment: Indeed this is merely an aesthetic problem when performing `SELECT * FROM` queries (I don't rely on column order in any case). Thanks for the tip regarding copying the table.

Comment: Maybe you could run multiple `alter table` statements? First, rename the column, then add a new column with the right name at the right position (`alter table add` supports positioning), and finally dropping the old column. Or use `rename table` and then `create table ... as select`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thanks, I tested both solutions and they worked perfectly (IMHO the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` is more elegant than copying and renaming columns). If you converted your comment into an answer I'd be glad to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 does not currently support re-ordering columns. You would need to run multiple statements:

- First, rename the column, then add a new column with the right name at the right position (`alter table add` supports positioning), and finally drop the old column.
- Or, probably more elegant, use `rename table` and then `create table ... as select`.