# Adding a column to table with SQL

Tags: sql, database, h2

I have a SQL problem with a h2 database. I want to add a column but always get an error although I strictly stick to the [syntax](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_add).

Example:

```
create table t1 (c1 bool,c3 bool);
alter table t1 add column c2 bool after c1;
```

Creating the table is no problem. But when it comes to the second line a get the following error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE T1 ADD COLUMN C2 BOOL AFTER[*] C1 "; SQL statement:
alter table t1 add column c2 bool after c1 [42000-168] 42000/42000 (Help)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The same error message is displayed when I omit "column":

```
alter table t1 add c2 bool after c1;
```

Comment: `column` must not be there

Comment: I also tried it without column (see my edit).

Comment: What happens if you dont wirte `after c1`?

Comment: Then it works but it adds my the new column at the last position which I don't want.

Comment: Try leaving out `after`. I noticed that [someone else](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44348/h2-alter-table-add-column-before-after) has also had problems with that. And documentation (http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_add) clearly states that both `column` and `after`should be supported.

Comment: Looks like H2 doesn't support reordering, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812765/h2-database-reorder-columns-using-sql) Thomas Mueller come with some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the column

```
create table t1 (c1 bool,c3 bool);
alter table t1 add c2 bool after c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the posted H2 documentation link the syntax for `ALTER` is

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CREATEDATE TIMESTAMP
```

So from your posted `ALTER` query as below, only difference it inclusion of `column`

```
alter table t1 add column c2 bool after c1;
```

**EDIT:**

Per H2 Spec `AFTER` and `BEFORE` should work but if it doesn't work then spec is wrong. In that case, either try removing `AFTER c1` or try using `BEFORE c3` instead of `AFTER c1`.

Comment: That also doesn't help. It gives me the same error.

Comment: Hmm ... then the Spec is wrong. BTW, try removing `after c1` and see. Or instead of saying `after c1` .. say `before c3`

Comment: Ahh!! great. Then it's time for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to Rahul I've found a way to solve a problem although the solution doesn't tell me why my first approach didn't succeed.

Instead of using "after" using "before" doesn't invoke error messages:

```
alter table t1 add column c2 bool before c3;
```