# How to rearrange the column position in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to re-arrange the column names in PostgreSQL table with records

```
entityid formattedfilename 
-------- ----------------- 
1        file1             
2        file2
```

Re-arrange below format with record

```
formattedfilename entityid 
----------------- -------- 
file1             1        
file2             2
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to switch the table's column order?

Comment: do you want to rearrange the ordinal position of the columns in the table ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23423817/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126430 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1243547/330315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `VIEW` for this,
see following demo

```
create table foo (entityid int,formattedfilename text);

insert into foo values (1,'file1');
insert into foo values (2,'file2');

select * from foo
```

RESULT

```
entityid formattedfilename 
-------- ----------------- 
1        file1             
2        file2
```

Now create a view like below

```
create or replace view vfoo as 
select formattedfilename,entityid from foo .

select * from vfoo
```

RESULT

```
formattedfilename entityid 
----------------- -------- 
file1             1        
file2             2
```

---

Still you want to do it with the table itself then refer : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Answer (score -1):

Just select it something like:

```
SELECT formattedfilename, entityid
FROM mytable
```

if you want `SELECT *` should return you that format then i would say you better have a view over your table and query on view.

Comment: either create view or recreate table in that case.