# How to use alter modify properly?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have table like this:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| car_id | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vin    | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color  | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year   | varchar(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| make   | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model  | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price  | decimal(10,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the content of the table:

```
+--------+------+-------+------+----------+----------+-----------+
| car_id | vin  | color | year | make     | model    | price     |
+--------+------+-------+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | NULL | gray  | 1998 | Porsche  | Boxter   | 17992.540 |
|      2 | NULL | NULL  | 2000 | Jaguar   | XJ       | 15995.000 |
|      3 | NULL | red   | 2002 | Cadillac | Escalade | 40215.900 |
+--------+------+-------+------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

when I want (for example)to put price column after color column:

```
alter table car_table modify column price after color;
```

it says:

> mysql> alter table car_table modify column price after color; ERROR
>   1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'after color' at line 1

it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move columns in a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Don't forget to include the datatype of the column you're moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below query
You have missed to include the datatype,

```
ALTER TABLE car_table MODIFY price decimal(10,3) AFTER color;
```