# MySQL - phpmyadmin - swap columns

Tags: mysql

I try swap 3 columns in my table. I try this :

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE px()
BEGIN
  DECLARE temp VARCHAR(20);
  update `idsaccess` set 
       temp = referer,
       referer = size_var,
       size_var = agent,
       agent = temp
    WHERE  agent like '%210%' ; 
END $$

CALL p
```

It don't work. It give me that error: `Unknown column 'temp' in 'field list'` I do not understand that: temp is varchar value not a column. I also try remove DECLARE and PROCEDURE and just set variable with @. Like this:

```
set @temp = '';    
update `idsaccess`
    set    @temp = referer,
           referer = size_var,
           size_var = agent
           agent = @temp
    WHERE  agent like '%210%'
```

It don't work either. It give me. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax`. Any idea what is wrong in my code ? And to avoid misunderstanding I don't want move columns. I just want swap SOME rows (WHERE  agent like '%210%') from one column to another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move columns in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805426/how-to-move-columns-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: To move columns, you make an `ALTER TABLE` statement, not a procedure. See the linked Q/A.

Comment: you can try creating a temporary table  and join to update. drop it once updation is done

Comment: but i dont want move all rows in table, just some of them where agent like '%210%'.

Comment: bingi : i try join, problem is that i don't have id in my table or any unique column.

Comment: not even combination of columns as unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after taking a backup... I tried for table I have with 2 columns and worked

```
UPDATE idsaccess   SET referer=@tmp:=referer, referer=size_var, size_var = agent, agent = @tmp  WHERE  agent like '%210%';
```