# How to change the column position of MySQL table without losing column data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change the column positions of my database table without losing data.

**For example:**

Current table:

```
+----+------+-------+----------+
| id | name | email | password |
+----+------+-------+----------+
```

to

```
+----+----------+------+-------+
| id | password | name | email |
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY password varchar(20) AFTER id
```

Comment: Does this reset records that had the `table_name` originally set?

Comment: @fungusanthrax yes, it does.

Comment: As given, field properties other than Type will be set to the default and Comment will be lost.  You may need to use  <br/> 
    ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY field_name varchar(20) NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '' COMMENT  'Comment goes here' AFTER id

Comment: Or `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name varchar(20) FIRST;` if you want to make it the first column.

Comment: might be good to include a `, ALGORITHM = INPLACE, LOCK = NONE` at the end too

Answer (score 40):

Hearaman's answer is correct; but if you are using phpMyAdmin, there is a visual and practical way to do that.

1. Open the table
2. Choose the "**Structure**" tab
3. Click on "**Move columns**"
4. Drag and drop column names

[image: Move columns link, middle of the Structure tab] [image: Move columns popup]

Comment: How the heck you find a "move column" option.

Comment: @SouravSarkar ıt should be right under the table showing the structure. Version differences may apply though.

Comment: In which @version you saw the option?

Comment: @SouravSarkar I am currently on version 4.5.4.1, but am also pretty sure it has been there for quite a while now (probably since version 4.0).

Comment: Hi @David . I'm afraid that is not the case. Reordering table columns on the Browse tab does not change the actual column order, and leaves phpMyAdmin instructions on how to show the column order instead. If you try to view the table with another tool (DataGrip for example) afterwards, you'll see that the column order is unchanged. "Move columns" button on the "Structure" tab is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @ArmanOzak - yep, I must have eaten something off that day. I was positive enough in the moment to post the correction, and I clearly see now that I was wrong. I deleted my prior comment to avoid confusion for other readers.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using MySQL workbench,

1. **Right-click on table**
2. **Alter table**
3. **drag columns and re-order**
4. **click apply and finish**

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN column_name column_name data_type AFTER another_column_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use modify/change keyword.

```
ALTER TABLE [table] CHANGE COLUMN [column] [column] [column definition] AFTER [column]

ALTER TABLE [table] MODIFY COLUMN [column] [column definition] AFTER [column]
```

Eg:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY password varchar(20) AFTER id

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY password varchar(20) varchar(20) AFTER id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me, using MySQL workbench and got lost trying to implement @Mohemmed Niyaz answer,
you can follow these steps,

- On your top left, click Schemas
- find and select your database, then find and select the table you want to modify
- When you hover over the table name you would see three icons, click on settings (that is the one in the middle) or you can right-click and select `Alter Table`
  ,
- then click on the column and drag it to the position you want your column to be.
- on your bottom right you will see apply (click and apply).