# How to move a certain SQL column to a different location within the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say my table looks like that:

```
B, C, D, A
```

How can I move 'A' to the first location?

Comment: Why would you do that? Can you give us a reason?

Comment: @WasteD What if accidentally my ID column is in the middle of the table?

Comment: This is purely cosmetic. The data itself is not stored in any order, rows or columns. You can alter how this data is displayed in the query

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: And why you want to do that? You can select the columns in whatever order you want. Does it matter at runtime in what order the columns are ? Do you have any specific requirement. It's not possible to do via SQL statements. You can do it from SQL management studio for sure..

Comment: @oneman You can just change the order of you select-statement: Your table is B,C,D,A so just do `SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table;`

Comment: @WasteD You're right. It's totally cosmetic thing, like JohnHC said. Just thought there's a possibility for that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: Using Select * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). Outside of using `select *`, there should be no way that the column order matters.

Comment: The only valid use case I can think of is for self-documentation purposes. I've seen tables where the primary and natural keys are WAY back at nearly the end of the table. That's very sloppy, and a tell-tale sign that there was no actual database design process.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that columns in a SQL table necessarily have any internal order.  Rather, the order in which a column, or derivation of a column, appear in a result set depend on the order which you set when you `SELECT`.

If you want to change the order of the columns in SQL Server Management Studio, then follow the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337556.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you.

[Change Column Order in a Table in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/aa337556.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, this is cosmetic. Maybe someone needs this done for no reason whatsoever.

So, for the sake of argument, I'll write a thing for you...

```
select *
into #supertemp
from Mytable

drop table MyTable

create table MyTable (A INT,           -- replace with your datatypes in the correct column order
                      B varchar(30),
                      C datetime,
                      D INT)

insert into MyTable
select A,B,C,D
from #SuperTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for OCD fellas like myself: Export the old structure to a new one, created with the desired column order.

Another option (for tables of *manageable size*), is to use the SSMS Design option. Just drag and drop the columns and place them in the desired order. Can't be easier than that.

P.S. Don't forget to drop and re-create all the indexes before and after the modification!

Answer (score -2):

You can modify column with MODIFY command without losing data.

Check this in:

[How to change the column position of MySql table without losing column data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718905/how-to-change-the-column-position-of-mysql-table-without-losing-column-data)

You can do that:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY password varchar(20) AFTER id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this question is on SQL Server, not MySQL.