# `MODIFY COLUMN` vs `CHANGE COLUMN`

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I know, we cannot rename a column using `MODIFY COLUMN` syntax, but we can using `CHANGE COLUMN` syntax.

My question is: what is the main usage of `modify syntax`?

For example:

```
ALATER TABLE tablename CHANGE col1 col1 INT(10) NOT NULL;
```

instead of

```
ALATER TABLE tablename MODIFY col1 INT(10) NOT NULL;
```

---

## Edited (question replaced)

- What is the main usage of `MODIFY` syntax?
- Why we have to use `CHANGE COLUMN` instead of `MODIFYCOLUMN`?

Comment: Because that's what the creators of mysql decided I guess

Comment: Probably because people underestimate the value of naming things.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

### `CHANGE COLUMN`

If you have already created your MySQL database, and decide after the fact that one of your columns is named incorrectly, you don't need to remove it and make a replacement, you can simply rename it using **change column**.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHANGE COLUMN foo bar VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL FIRST;
```

---

### `MODIFY COLUMN`

This command does everything `CHANGE COLUMN` can, but **without renaming** the column. You can use the `MODIFY` SQL command if you need to resize a column in MySQL. By doing this you can allow more or less characters than before. You can't rename a column using `MODIFY` and other.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY COLUMN foo VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL AFTER baz;
```

---

#### Note

`ALTER TABLE` is used for *altering* a table in order to change column name, size, drop column etc. `CHANGE COLUMN` and `MODIFY COLUMN` commands cannot be used without help of `ALTER TABLE` command.

Comment: what is the term `FIRST` and `AFTER` are they keyword in `sql`?

Comment: `FIRST` - will be the first colum on table from the left side; `AFTER col_name` - column will be located after this col_name.

Comment: it's especially useful for adding comments with `comment 'my comment'` on columns without having to retype the column's name in the statement.

Answer (score 39):

The difference is whether you want to change the column name, column definition or both.

#### CHANGE

Can change a column name or definition, or both
`ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE a b BIGINT NOT NULL`

#### MODIFY

Can change a column definition but not its name
`ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY b INT NOT NULL`

#### RENAME COLUMN (from MySQL 8.0)

Can change a column name but not its definition
`ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME COLUMN b TO a`

---

*Also, `CHANGE` and `MODIFY` can be followed by an optional `COLUMN` keyword.*

For complete explanation:

1. [MySQL 5.7 Docs- Renaming, Redefining, and Reordering Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-redefine-column)
2. [MySQL 8.0 Docs- Renaming, Redefining, and Reordering Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-redefine-column)

Comment: Most complete and concise answer.

Comment: One thing missing though - **CHANGE DEFAULT**: used to set or remove the default value for a column, e.g. `ALTER TABLE Foo ALTER COLUMN bar SET DEFAULT ‘hello world’;`.

Comment: Also, `CHANGE` and `MODIFY` can be followed by an optional `COLUMN` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

I found one difference after more than an hour of effort in trying to make a non auto_increment column into auto_increment
statement:

```
alter table `doctor_experience` modify column `id` int(11) unsigned auto_increment
```

works, but statment:

```
alter table `doctor_experience` change column `id` `id` int(11) unsigned auto_increment
```

will report an error.

Answer (score 2):

That is the same. It was done to support another syntax (Oracle ALTER TABLE as I know). You can use both of them.

Note: `ALTER TABLE CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name` syntax allows renaming column using one command.

Answer (score 2):

Change Column : Used when we want to change the column name with its definition.
eg - alter table `student` CHANGE `name` `full_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL;

Modify column : Used when column name is to be same but change in its definition.
eg - alter table `student` MODIFY `full_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;

Rename column : Used when we only need to change the column name (its definition will be same)
alter table `student` RENAME COLUMN `full_name` TO `name`;

Answer (score 0):

You can change a column name using the change statement

```
ALTER TABLE x
CHANGE COLUMN id emp_id VARCHAR(20) NULL;(You are changing the column id to emp_id)
```

The modify statement does not change the value in the column but changes the datatype (for example, from Text to DATE etc)

```
ALTER TABLE x
MODIFY COLUMN emp_date DATE;
```