# Trying To Change MYSQL's Table Field Type From BLOB to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, blob

I keep getting an error when trying to run a statement for the MySql database. What I am trying to do is change column name's type from BLOB to JSON.

Here is the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` JSON CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

This is something that workbench automatically created for me and when I ran it... I get this error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` JSON CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` JSON CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql) SO question?

Comment: No, that did not answer my question. If I run a statement from that answer I get another error: <br/>ERROR 3144: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
MODIFY `name` JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simplify the command and eliminate the parts you aren't changing:

```
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` JSON;
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem is this error:                                                        ERROR 3144: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` JSON

Comment: Sounds like the table is populated, and the existing data can't be converted. You may have to create a new table, and write a query that will copy the data over, with explicit conversion of the JSON data.

Comment: You're the best. It worked after I cleared my table. Thanks <3

Comment: how can i convert explicitly from blob to json? I got the same error  Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.

Comment: @SathiyaVasagamS, see David's answer below. You may have to do it in multiple steps.

Comment: no. when I modify also got the same error. direct conversion via query its not working for me

Answer (score 3):

How about converting the column to JSON in two steps via TEXT?

```
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` MODIFY `name` TEXT;
ALTER TABLE `main_db`.`main_table` MODIFY `name` JSON;
```

Using [MODIFY instead of CHANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767174/modify-column-vs-change-column#14767467) because you did not need to rename the column.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do, explicitly convert, drop old column, and rename temp column:

```
alter table testjson add jdata json;
update testjson set jdata = cast(convert(cast(xdata as char(999999)) using utf8) as json);
alter table testjson drop column xdata;
alter table testjson change column jdata xdata json;
```

Worth noting here There's a related trick in LOAD..INFILE:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/tmp/another.csv" INTO TABLE another(@hid, @htype, @bindata) set id=unhex(@hid), type=unhex(@htype), jdata=cast(convert(cast(@bindata as char(999999)) using utf8) as json);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the existing data you need to create a new temp column of json format.
copy the data in blob column into the temp column by casting it into string type.

```
update main_db set temp = CAST(name AS CHAR(100000));
```

now rename both the columns and you will get back the existing data.