# Add column after another column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

How can I add a column after another column to a database using Alembic or SQLAlchemy? That would be equivalent to [this SQL clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934335/2100933):

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo
CHANGE COLUMN bar
bar COLUMN_DEFINITION_HERE
AFTER OTHER_COLUMN;
-- or
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN baz AFTER bar;
```

I also tried the suggestion in [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-alembic/izYq2EMYotI), but it didn't help.

While the order doesn't matter when querying, it helps readability for large tables when in the SQL shell.

Comment: There's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541312/alter-table-add-multiple-columns-after-column1

Comment: @mba12: that's about the SQL syntax, not on how to do this with SQLAlchemy's tooling.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query :

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD New_column_name column_definition AFTER column_name;

Answer (score -4):

Use `ALTER` with `AFTER` to specify where to place the column.

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
CHANGE COLUMN foo1 foo1 INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER foo2;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax the OP wants to *generate* using either of the SQLAlchemy schema migration management tools, so Alembic or SQLAlchemy-Migrate. Your answer doesn't cover that.